# MapBox polygon Drawing

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, polygon

I'm using MapBox for my app. I need to draw a polygon around a specific area in my map. and the polygon can draw correctly. but the issue is that when i zooming or moving map region the polygon lines are blinking ore hided from some areas. i try to change width of line but still issue exists.
 [Screenshot of map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I2TX.png) - In the screenshot the partially visible white line is polygon. And the orange line is drawn by annotation with image view.

code used for update width of line:

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, lineWidthForPolylineAnnotation annotation: MGLPolyline) -> CGFloat {
return 10
 }

Comment: Hello! Could you share which version of the Mapbox Maps SDK for iOS you are using, as well as whether you are seeing this on devices? If you believe you are seeing a bug in the SDK, please [open an issue on Github](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues),

Comment: Hi. Thanks for reply.

Comment: Am using Mapbox-iOS-SDK 4.6.0 . in iPad mini 3 (os - 11.2.2). I think in simulator (iPad Air (11.3))it works properly.